# What to assign to a variable to act like ":" in pandas dataframe .loc method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I'm trying to create a function that takes in list and results a subsetted index. If there is no index provided I want it to give me back the entire index.

I thought that `None` works for this in `pandas` but apparently not... I'm using `pandas '0.23.4'`

**Is there another value I can give the slicing method that will act like: `df.loc[:,"sepal_length"]` that I can assign to a variable?** I can't do `index=:`

```
df = X_iris.copy()
print(df.columns, df.index[:5], "", sep="\n")
# Index(['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width'], dtype='object')
# Index(['iris_0', 'iris_1', 'iris_2', 'iris_3', 'iris_4'], dtype='object')


def example(df, index):
    result = df.loc[index,"sepal_length"]
    print("index =", index, "works")
    return result

example(df, "iris_0")
# index = iris_0 works
# 5.1
example(df, None)
# TypeError: cannot use label indexing with a null key
```

Comment: You want a slice object. `slice(None)` probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `slice(None)`:

```
df
       sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width
iris_0            x           x            x           x
iris_1            x           x            x           x
iris_2            x           x            x           x
iris_3            x           x            x           x
iris_4            x           x            x           x
```

```
df.loc['iris_0', "sepal_length"]
# 'x'

df.loc[slice(None), "sepal_length"]
iris_0    x
iris_1    x
iris_2    x
iris_3    x
iris_4    x
Name: sepal_length, dtype: object
```

You can also use `Ellipsis` (`...`) when indexing on the underlying NumPy array:

```
# df.to_numpy()[..., df.columns.get_loc('sepal_length')]
df.values[..., df.columns.get_loc('sepal_length')]
# array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x'], dtype=object)
```